# Is there a way to add new values to a collection_select field in a form in Rails 6?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, user-interface

In my blog app, there are posts and each post can optionally have tags. When the user is on the new or edit post form, they currently have the means to select or deselect tags to associate with the post. There is a many-to-many relationship between the post and tag models and I am using bootstrap, bootstrap_form and bootstrap-select. This all works seemingly very well. The problem is, when the user is assigning tags to their post, these tags currently have to already exist (otherwise they would have to abort their post and go add tags...bad user experience). I am trying to devise a way to give the user the option to create new tags and/or select already-existing tags and apply them to the post, all on the same post form in the collection_select field, all at the same time.

Apparently I'm asking the wrong questions on google...wouldn't this be a common need, already solved?

I am asking for guidance in providing an 'add new tag' functionality to an otherwise functional collection_select field. How best to go about this?

Posts Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: %i[edit update interim destroy]


  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin_role
      if params[:tag]
        @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag]).all.order('updated_at DESC').page params[:page]
      else
        @posts = Post.all.order('updated_at DESC').page params[:page]
      end
    else
      if params[:tag]
        @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag]).where(published: true).order('updated_at DESC').page params[:page]
      else
        @posts = Post.where(published: true).order('updated_at DESC').page params[:page]
      end
    end

  end


  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
    @categories = Category.pluck(:name, :id)
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @categories = Category.pluck(:name, :id)
    @cat = @post.category_id
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.create(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        if params[:interim]
          format.html { redirect_to edit_post_path(@post), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
          format.json { redirect_to edit_post_path(@post), status: :created, location: @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        elsif params[:complete]
          format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
        end
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        if params[:interim]
          format.html { redirect_to edit_post_path(@post), notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { redirect_to edit_post_path(@post), status: :ok, location: @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        elsif params[:complete]
          format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
        end
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private


  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end


  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :user_id, :published, :category_id, :tag_list, :tag, { tag_ids: [] }, :tag_ids,
      comment_attributes: [:id, :title, :user_id, :content, :post_id, :parent_id, :ancestry, :commentable, :commentable_id, :commentable_type])
  end
end
```

No tags controller (not needed thus far)

Post Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
    has_rich_text :content

    include PgSearch::Model
    multisearchable :against => [:title, :content]

    def self.published(post)
      post.published
    end

    def self.tagged_with(name)
      Tag.find_by!(name: name).posts
    end

    def self.tag_counts
      Tag.select('tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count').joins(:taggings).group('taggings.tag_id')
    end

    def tag_list
      tags.map(&:name).join(', ')
    end

    def tag_list=(names)
      self.tags = names.split(',').map do |n|
        Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
      end
    end

end
```

Tag Model:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :posts, through: :taggings
end
```

Tagging Model:

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Post Form Partial (the actual new and edit views do nothing but render this form):

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @post, local: true, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.rich_text_area :content, control_class: 'trix-content-edit' %>

  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>

  <%= f.form_group :published, label: { text: "Publication Status" } do %>
    <%= f.radio_button :published, true, label: "Published" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :published, false, label: "Draft" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.collection_select :tag_ids, Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, {label: 'Tags', include_blank: true}, {class: 'selectpicker show-tick', multiple: 'multiple', title: 'Make your selection...', 'data-live-search': 'true', 'data-actions-box': 'true'} %>

  <br><br>
  <%= f.submit "Save and Resume Editing", name: "interim", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= f.submit "Save and Quit", name: "complete", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <br><br>

<% end %>
```

No forms for tag at this time.

Comment: You can create nested records in the same form by using [`accepts_nested_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [`fields_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for). But from a UX and code organization standpoint I would just use ajax to to send a request a separate tags controller and create the tags on the fly.

Comment: @max Thanks for your response...you've shifted my thinking toward JavaScript for a solution whereas up until now I was stuck in strictly rails.